# Powershell: if items in array1 contain items in array2, what am I doing wrong here

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement, contains

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
    $ZertoGenericAlert =  "VRA0030"
    $ZvmToVraConnection = "ZVM0002"
    $ZvmToZvmConnection = "ZVM0003", "ZVM0004"

  $thoseerrors = "ZVM0002", "VPG0006", "VPG0004" , "ZVM0003", "ZVM0004"

  if ($thoseerrors -contains $ZvmToZvmConnection) {Echo "bingo"} Else {Echo "fail"}
```

It keeps coming as "fail" when I run that that entire piece of code

It gives me "Bingo" when **ONLY 1 item**  is found in the `$zvmtozvmconnection`

Ie I remove "ZVM0004" and only "ZVM003" remains i get "Bingo"

I also tested `-match` and that did not work either

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify if any string in one array exists in second array of strings with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822027/identify-if-any-string-in-one-array-exists-in-second-array-of-strings-with-power)

Comment: `$array = 4,5,6;  1,2,$array,3,4 -contains $array` -> `$true`. If tests if the object on the right is in the array on the left. If one array *contains the other array*. (By memory reference, not by matching content values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-contains` doesn't work that way. It checks if a single item is contained in an array. `-in` is the same, with the other order (`$array -contains $item` or `$item -in $array`).

You should use the `Compare-Object` cmdlet for this:

```
if ((Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $thoseerrors -DifferenceObject $ZvmToZvmConnection -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual)) {
    'bingo'
} else {
    'fail'
}
```

Comment: thank you... I guess they should fix the notes and help on Powershell ISE, which states that it checks if array 1 contains AT LEAST ONE of items in array 2 ... O well .. sigh... thank you

Comment: @A.Zia interesting, where did you see that?

Comment: @A.Zia that text is correct and is not what you described. The text says that the item must match exactly at least one of the values in the array, consider an array like `$a = 1,2,3,3`, in that case `$a -contains 3` is true, even though `$a` contains `3` more than once.

Comment: I see , so I was misinterpreting the description

Answer (score 3):

other method

```
$resul=$ZvmToZvmConnection | where {$_ -in $thoseerrors} | select -First 1

if ($resul) 
{
    'bingo'
} 
else 
{
    'fail'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one liner:

```
if($thoseerrors | ? {$ZvmToZvmConnection -contains $_}) {Echo "bingo"} Else {Echo "fail"}
```

And with all errors in a separated array.

```
# Existing errors stored in $errors
$errors = $thoseerrors | Where {$ZvmToZvmConnection -contains $_}

# Check if the $errors array contains elements
if($errors){Echo "bingo"} Else {Echo "fail"}
```